# displaying specific error messages in laravel 4.2

Tags: laravel, laravel-4, laravel-validation

hello i have this form and i have validations for it. I have already finished doing the validations for in inside my controller and i can already display the error messages in my view but i wanted the error message to be beside the input area where it came from 
here is my code in the view

```
{{ Form::open(array('url' => 'addParentAccnt')) }}
    <div class="form-group">
        {{ Form::label('username', 'Username') }}
        {{ Form::text('username', Input::old('username'), array('class' => 'form-control','placeholder' => 'Insert username')) }}
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        {{ Form::label('fName', 'First Name') }}
        {{ Form::text('fName', Input::old('fName'), array('class' => 'form-control','placeholder' => 'Insert First Name')) }}
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        {{ Form::label('lName', 'Last Name') }}
        {{ Form::text('lName', Input::old('lName'), array('class' => 'form-control','placeholder' => 'Insert Last Name')) }}
    </div> {{ Form::submit('Proceed to Next Step', array('class' => 'btn btn-primary')) }}

{{ Form::close()}}
```

in the bottom of my view i added this code to display the error messages

```
@if ($errors->any())
<ul>
   {{ implode('', $errors->all('<p style="color:red"              class="error">:message</p>')) }}
</ul>
@endif
```

the code inside my controller is this

```
$rules = array
(
'username'     => 'required|min:10|max:50',
'fName'        => 'required|alpha|min:1|max:80',
'lName'        => 'required|alpha|min:1|max:80', 
);
$validator = Validator::make(Input::all(), $rules, $messages);
if ($validator->fails()) 
{   
  return Redirect::to('createPa')
  ->withErrors($validator)
  ->withInput(Input::except('password'));
} 
else
{
   //do something
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change your view as following:

```
 <div class="form-group">
            {{ Form::label('username', 'Username') }}
            {{ Form::text('username', Input::old('username'), array('class' => 'form-control','placeholder' => 'Insert username')) }}
            {{ $errors->first('username', ':message') }}
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
            {{ Form::label('fName', 'First Name') }}
            {{ Form::text('fName', Input::old('fName'), array('class' => 'form-control','placeholder' => 'Insert First Name')) }}
            {{ $errors->first('fName', ':message') }}
        </div>
```